# ZeroMQ / zmq publisher subscriber backwards compatibility: 2.2 SUB-s / 4.1.4 PUB-s

Tags: c++, zeromq

I want to upgrade zmq from 2.2 to 4.1.4 on some specific machines without interrupting the flow of messages to other machines that are still running 2.2.0.

A problem I've noticed so far is that a v2 subscriber doesn't receive any messages from a v4 publisher (other way around works fine).

Here's my theory as to why:
In versions 3 and up, filtering of messages happens at the publisher, while in version 2 filtering happens at the subscriber (this change was documented here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeromq/zeromq3-x/master/NEWS under v 3.0.0).

The zguide example for `PUB/SUB` tracing in v3 shows that when a subscriber adds a subscription, the `PUB` gets notified that a subscription has been added, which makes sense since the filtering happens at the publisher. With a v2 subscriber (which does the filtering itself), those messages aren't sent to the publisher, so my v4 publisher doesn't know that the v2 `SUB` has connected, and the `PUB` silently drops the packets.

From the guide: (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc115)

"The subscriber thread subscribes to "A" and "B", receives five messages, and then destroys its socket. When you run the example, the listener prints two subscription messages, five data messages, two unsubscribe messages, and then silence:"

```
[002] 0141  // subscribe to "A"
[002] 0142  // subscribe to "B"
[007] B-91164
[007] B-12979
[007] A-52599
[007] A-06417
[007] A-45770
[002] 0041  // unsubscribe to "A"
[002] 0042  // unsubscribe to "B"
```

"This shows neatly how the publisher socket stops sending data when there are no subscribers for it. The publisher thread is still sending messages. The socket just drops them silently"

**Is there a workaround for this?**

ZMQ says "All 4.x releases aim for compatibility with stable releases back to 2.2.0" but that could easily just refer to compatibility of the APIs, not the messaging.